# PHP preg match for extracting emails from txt files

Tags: php

So, let me start be stating my goal.
Our organization is trying to send automated emails to users whos user details may have been compromised so that they can change their passwords, so we will be taking large dumps of data that includes a bunch of stuff and the users email.
We need to use PHP to extract the emails from the txt files and send email via mail() function.

I can handle the email sending part of it, but what I need is a perfect preg_match for putting the emails into an array while the dumps don't follow a standard pattern of any kind because we will be getting them from all over the place.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you simply take the emails from your user database? I find it difficult to believe that you don't already know what your users' emails are.

Comment: They aren't our users, they are random people who's info we only obtain from an info dump on pastebin. We are just trying to provide a public service and notify users that their info has been compromised when we come across it.

Comment: I see. Well, it's not as if your regex can't be found by just googling "email validation regex for PHP". Then, preg_match_all() will be your friend. But what you're doing, even with the best intentions, might be construed as spam.Also, I am afraid that the question as it stands is a poor fit for this site. You will find it useful, I think, to check out the question-asking tutorial.

Comment: Thank you but it appears that all the preg_match expressions I have found don't account for lack of uniform formatting around the email.

Comment: 'Lack of uniform formatting' -- what is that? You can probably add a "word boundary" match character at the beginning and end of the regex. It should be unnecessary, however. If you have something terrifying (and unlikely) like "...this.is@email.com.andthis@istoo.net.johndoe@gnail.com...", you're not going to be able to perform a reliable extraction in any case, and might just as well give up.

Comment: Thanks I gound one that works for now. Most of the emails are usually in email:password format so we are just taking advantage of that.